# How to find terminated instances based on IP address in AWS CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-config

I am trying to find a terminated EC2 instance in CloudTrail based on a Primary Private IP, but no luck.

I also tried looking at AWS Config resource timeline. Not savvy with AWS Config Advance queries either. Even in that case I would need to look for a parameter of CloudTrail "Event Record" corresponding to IP information.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to use AWS Athena to query your CloudTrail trails stored in S3 as explained in AWS docs:

- [Querying AWS CloudTrail Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems I also face. I want to trace the ec2 instances id based on IP  and from the AWS console, it's very difficult to trace. So I write a PowerShell script that helps me to find the instance id with the associated IP address.

Hope this will help you.

```
$instanceList = @("i-01f4da30bad3b", "i-06eaa91009872", "i-06ab536ca4e"")

foreach($eachInstance in $instanceList)
{
    $configuration_json  = aws configservice get-resource-config-history --resource-type AWS::EC2::Instance --resource-id $eachInstance --region us-west-2 | ConvertFrom-JSON
    $instanceIP = (($configuration_json.configurationItems.configuration)[1] | ConvertFrom-JSON).PrivateIPAddress
    $instanceID = (($configuration_json.configurationItems.configuration)[1] | ConvertFrom-JSON).instanceId
    Write-Host "$instanceID - $instanceIP"
    
}
```